# Weird Behaviour When Changing the tabindex in onchange Handler in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asynchronous, onchange, tabindex

Given the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function updateTabIndex() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById("id1")
      elem.setAttribute("tabIndex", 2)
      elem.setAttribute("value", "now: tabindex 2")
    }, 100)
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Weird Behaviour When Changing the tabindex in onchange Handler in Internet
    Explorer</h1>
  <p><input id="id1" tabindex="-1" value="tabindex: (-1)"/></p>
  <p><select tabindex="1" size="1" onchange="updateTabIndex()" onpropertychange="updateTabIndex()">
    <option>tabindex 1 - an option</option>
    <option>tabindex 1 - another option</option>
  </select></p>
  <p><input tabIndex="3" value="tabindex 3"/></p>


  <h2>Instructions</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Open this page in IE. To be precise, the problem is reproducible in 
    (at least):
    <ul>
      <li>IE 8, Version 8.0.6001.18702CO on Windows XP and</li>
      <li>IE 9, Version 9.0.8112.16421 on Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Use the <em>mouse</em> to change the value of the select box.</li>
    <li>As you can see, the onchange handler is called and changes the tabindex
    of the first input element.</li>
    <li>If you now tab out of the select box, you can see that the tab order is
    adhered to correctly: you go from the select box to the first input element
    and then to the last element on the page.</li>
    <li>Close the page and open it again.</li>
    <li>Click on the third input element and press Shift + Tab to enter the select
    box.</li>
    <li>Use the down arrow key on the keyboard to change the selected value in the
    select box.</li>
    <li>Now tab out of the select box.</li>
    <li>As you can see, the onchange handler is called, as before (the text in 
    the first input field has changed).</li>
    <li>However, if you tab around now, you will see that the tabindex attribute
    is ignored. Instead the order of the elements in the document source is used
    as the tab order.</li>
    <li>Even if you change the select box value with the mouse now, the tab
    order remains broken. To test again, you need to close the page and open
    it again or reload it by entering the url bar and pressing enter. Hitting
    F5 will not be enough.</li>
 </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

IE ignores the changed tab order when the select box value (which triggers the change to the tabindex attribute) is changed by some keyboard action (arrow keys) but does not ignore the tabindex change when the select box value is changed with the mouse (see more detailed explanation 
about the expected and perceived behaviour in html above).

Why does IE behaves like that? In particular, why is the behaviour different when using the mouse and when using the keys. Is it a bug in IE? Right now, I'm pretty sure it is a bug in IE here, but of course there is also the chance that I'm doing something wrong which just happens to work as expected in FF.

I already googled quite a bit, but as far as I can see, this bug (if it is one) has not been reported or discussed anywhere until now.

**Some remarks**

First of all, Firefox does not exhibit this weird behaviour.

Just to avoid being misunderstood, it is clear that, when I tab out from the
select box, I'll get to the to the input with tabindex 3, because the
asynchronous code in the onchange handler might not have been executed yet.
But after that (when the text in the first input has changed), I expect the
new tab order to be established. This is how FF behaves.

It seems that IE already fires the onchange event each time I use the up/down
arrow key and not when I leave the select box (as FF does). I'm not sure if
that is related to the problem.

Added Bonus: If you open the IE developer tools you will see that the tabIndex
attribute is set correctly in the DOM, also when changing the select box value
without the mouse. But the tabindex is ignored when tabbing around.

My (naive) guess is that IE keeps an internal representation of the taborder
and that this internal representation is not recalculated correctly in this
case.

More weirdness: You can delete lines 5 and 9 of this file (setTimeout call and
closing curly brace), so that the tabindex change is no longer called
asynchronously. It then works correctly if you enter the select with the mouse
and leave it by tabbing out. It still breaks if you tab into the select change
the value with the arrow key and tab out.

Comment: I put your code to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taer5/)...

Comment: For some reason jsfiddle.net seems to be not working for me in IE 9 right now. It hangs at "Initializing the awesome!". Not so awesome :-)

Comment: Close the DevTools when loading the fiddle, the open when it's completely loaded.

Comment: I didn't have them open. Also, in IE 8 the jsfiddle site seems broken. Anyway, this question is not about jsfiddle's IE compatibility :-)

Comment: It's also broken in IE 10 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found an interesting workaround: Just add

```
elem.parentNode.replaceChild(elem, elem)
```

after setting the tabindex makes it work. Seems this DOM manipulation triggers a recalculation of IE's internal tab order which is missing otherwise.

While this is better than no solution, it's quite an ugly hack. :-(

If anybody knows a different, less brute force solution, I'd be still interested.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSFiddle, changing your code to set the JavaScript property instead of the attribute seems to help...

```
  elem.tabIndex = 2;
  // elem.setAttribute("tabIndex", 2);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Before I posted the question, I tried all obvious alternatives:  elem.setAttribute("tabIndex", 2), elem.setAttribute("tabindex", 2), elem.tabIndex = 2, elem.tabindex = 2. None behaves as expected. It seems that you need to tab out of the select box after changing the value with the down arrow to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated the question to stress that you need to tab out of the select box to reproduce the problem correctly.

Comment: Oh, alas, there is no end to the weirdness of this. With your version it works if - immediately after hitting down arrow to change the value - the select box loses focus for example by clicking with the mouse on some empty area of the page. But it still does not work if you tab out after hitting the down arrow. My original version (with setAttribute) breaks in both cases. So your change indeed makes a different, though it does not solve the problem completely.

Comment: Oh and it also makes a difference if you enter the select box by tabbing into it or clicking on it with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when dealing with hidden radio buttons in IE 9. I set the tabIndex to -1, but you could still tab to the radio group. My workaround was to alter the CSS visibility property, which forced IE to ignore the group.

To conceal radio buttons from IE 9's strange tabbing behavior:

```
$radioBtns.attr('tabIndex', -1).css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

To reveal radio buttons and resume standard tabbing behavior:

```
$radioBtns.removeAttr('tabIndex').css('visibility', '');
```